# taking screen shot half of my screen for IOS?

Tags: ios

I try take screen shot half my screen and save it to photo library.
I use code below work just fine but it capture the all my screen .
all i need its half of my screen. I'm using xcode 4.4.Iknow there's a lot question
post about this .but i can't make it to work a got error.please help

```
IGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: I'm no expert on the iOS APIs, but I don't see anything in there that looks like an operation to crop the image.

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height/2.0));

Answer (score 0):

In your line `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bou‌​nds.size.height/2.0);`

Replace this line

Hope it helps you..